# Codeigniter : Change data display using select/option using foreach method

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying and testing out codeigniter at the moment. had to research my answers but no luck.
I want to display unique data via html's "select" and php's "foreach" method.

Model :

```
  public function get_medicalinfo($patient_id=datehistory)
 {
    return  $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('patient_info')
       ->where("patient_id",$patient_id)
    ->get()
    ->result();
 }
```

controller :

```
$data['getmedical'] = $this->patient_model->get_medicalinfo(@$patient_id);
```

view :

```
<select class="form-control" id="">
<option value="<?php echo @$getmedical->datehistory;?>"> <?php echo @$getmedical->datehistory;?></option>
<?php                       
foreach($getmedical as $row)
{ 
echo '<option value="'.$row->datehistory.'">'.$row->datehistory.'</option>';
}
 ?> 
</select>
```

so script works if you input a new patient, he will have a unique ID and it's patient history along with what i did to the patients. example: firstname, surname, diagnosis etc. <-this works perfectly fine.

what im having trouble is I don't know where and what to put the data in `"view"` upon selecting `"datehistory"`.